# Trying to a get a movable image with a PNG background using pygame

Tags: pygame

We are trying to create a program using pygame that allows preset image files to be dragged around over another PNG image as the background. Used some code from a tutorial for pygame and tweaked it to fit our specific needs. We have gotten the images to populate and are movable but only with a white background. When importing the PNG file for the background instead, the moveable image disappears behind the background. I have replace the the two filepaths with just "filepath." Still fairly new to python so sorry for ugly code.

Code:

```
# Import the library pygame
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

##background
bg = pygame.image.load(filepath)
 
# Take colors input
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

 
# Construct the GUI game
pygame.init()
 
# Set dimensions of game GUI
w, h = 1280, 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
 
# Take image as input
img = pygame.image.load(filepath)
img.convert()
 
# Draw rectangle around the image
rect = img.get_rect()
rect.center = w//2, h//2
 
# Set running and moving values
running = True
moving = False

# Setting what happens when game
# is in running state

while running:
    screen.blit(bg, (320,0))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Close if the user quits the
        # game
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
 
        # Making the image move
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                moving = True
 
        # Set moving as False if you want
        # to move the image only with the
        # mouse click
        # Set moving as True if you want
        # to move the image without the
        # mouse click
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            moving = False
 
        # Make your image move continuously
        elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION and moving:
            rect.move_ip(event.rel)

    
 
   # Set screen color and image on screen
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        screen.blit(img, rect)
 
    # Construct the border to the image
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, rect, 2)
 
    # Update the GUI pygame
    pygame.display.update()
    
    ##trying to draw the background
   
 
# Quit the GUI game
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code and through a bit of experimentation, came up with some refinements that display the image in front of the background.  Following is your program with a few tweaks.

```
# Import the library pygame
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

##background
bg = pygame.image.load("background.png")        # Just a sky blue background
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (1280, 720))    # Made it fit the screen size
 
# Take colors input
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

 
# Construct the GUI game
pygame.init()
 
# Set dimensions of game GUI
w, h = 1280, 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
 
# Take image as input
img = pygame.image.load("car.png")
img.convert()
 
# Draw rectangle around the image
rect = img.get_rect()
rect.center = w//2, h//2
 
# Set running and moving values
running = True
moving = False

# Setting what happens when game
# is in running state

while running:
    screen.blit(bg, (0,0))          # Start the background at the upper left
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Close if the user quits the
        # game
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
 
        # Making the image move
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                moving = True
 
        # Set moving as False if you want
        # to move the image only with the
        # mouse click
        # Set moving as True if you want
        # to move the image without the
        # mouse click
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            moving = False
 
        # Make your image move continuously
        elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION and moving:
            rect.move_ip(event.rel)

    
 
   # Set screen color and image on screen
    #screen.fill(WHITE)
    screen.blit(img, rect)                  # Changing the indentation seems to make it visible
 
    # Construct the border to the image
    #pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, rect, 2)
 
    # Update the GUI pygame
    pygame.display.update()
    
    ##trying to draw the background
   
 
# Quit the GUI game
pygame.quit()
```

Following are the highligts.

- I utilized a "png" file I had for a sky blue background which was loaded and then transformed to fill the entire 1280 x 720 screen.
- The placement of the background was set to start at the upper left; if your background image needs to be centered or oriented differently, keep that in mind.
- The indentation of the load of the image to be moved (in my case a "car") was revised to be a part of the "while" loop and not a part of the "for" loop; otherwise, the image only flashes and appears during the handling of the mouse events.

After those tweaks, the image appeared and was moved around by the mouse.

[image: Image and background example]

The takeaway from this is that you would want your image to be handled within your drawing/blit cycle.  That appears to be where you got tripped up.

Give that a try.